# CSS transition for navigation bar

Tags: css, css-transitions

I would like to add an animation for when you open the nav links menu on smaller screens. I dont really understand transitions and couldnt find a great source that would tell me how to do it this way. Was wondering if i could have any suggestions on how to do it.

The section I would like to animate is the dropdown that appears when you click the hamburger menu. So that it slowly opens from top to bottom.

Similarly to what w3 did here but vertically rather than horizontally.

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_sidebar.asp

Image for reference:
[image: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGcTP.png]]

```js
function ToggleNavLinks() {
  var navLink = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-links")[0];

  if (window.getComputedStyle(navLink).display === "none") {
    navLink.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    navLink.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
  .navbar {
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--bg-secondary);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-links {
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-links ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links li a {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.nav-links li a:hover {
  color: #4c6bc1;
}

.nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 21px;
  width: 30px;
}

.nav-toggle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-toggle .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .nav-toggle {
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .nav-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <img class="logo" alt="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">

      <a class="nav-toggle" onclick="ToggleNavLinks()">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Links used in the navbar -->
      <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <svg class="theme-toggle" alt="Icon used for toggling dark mode" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="moon" class="svg-inline--fa fa-moon fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M279.135 512c78.756 0 150.982-35.804 198.844-94.775 28.27-34.831-2.558-85.722-46.249-77.401-82.348 15.683-158.272-47.268-158.272-130.792 0-48.424 26.06-92.292 67.434-115.836 38.745-22.05 28.999-80.788-15.022-88.919A257.936 257.936 0 0 0 279.135 0c-141.36 0-256 114.575-256 256 0 141.36 114.576 256 256 256zm0-464c12.985 0 25.689 1.201 38.016 3.478-54.76 31.163-91.693 90.042-91.693 157.554 0 113.848 103.641 199.2 215.252 177.944C402.574 433.964 344.366 464 279.135 464c-114.875 0-208-93.125-208-208s93.125-208 208-208z"></path></svg>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div>
    {{{body}}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have a look at the tools available to you in the editor. It's all fairly self-explanatory. Please fix the snippet I created so it shows your problem.

Comment: I dont really know how to work code snippets. I essentially want it so the links pop out from top to bottom in a transition.